# Evaluation error with RunMean and mutate

Tags: r, dplyr, runtime-error

Here's my code:

```
install.packages('TTR')
library(dplyr)
library(TTR)

df <- data.frame(index = 1:20, name = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "A", "C", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "A", "A", "C", "B", "C", "A", "B", "D"), amount = c(10,14,3,4,15,9,12,6,7,8,10,13,12,6,8,8,9,3,14,10))

all_data=data.frame()
for (a in unique(df$name)){
data=df%>%filter(name==a)%>%mutate(last3avg=runMean(amount, n = 3, cumulative = FALSE))  
all_data=rbind(data,all_data)
}

all_data=all_data%>%arrange(index)
```

And here's the error:

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
>     Evaluation error: n = 3 is outside valid range: [1, 1].

Why is this error happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try running this:

```
runMean(df %>% filter(name == "A") %>% select(amount), n = 3, cumulative = FALSE)
```

Now, try this:

```
runMean(df %>% filter(name == "D") %>% select(amount), n = 3, cumulative = FALSE)
```

The difference is that `D` has only one entry, so `n = 3` makes no sense.

---

**Edit to address comment below**

To avoid the error, you could filter to ensure there are always at least 3 instances of each `name`. For example,

```
df %<>% group_by(name) %>% filter(n() >= 3) %>% ungroup
```

Comment: What would be the solution for it than?